# How to use code completion on SCSS files in IntelliJ IDEA 10.5?

Tags: intellij-idea, sass, code-completion

In general SCSS files are CSS files with some special features. When i want to edit a *.sass file in my project i noticed that IntelliJ knows that file type but there is no code completion at all. I know IntelliJ has code completion for CSS files.

Just going to "IDE Settings" / "File Types" / "Cascading style sheets" and adding "*.sass" and "*.scss" to it, brings auto completion to this file for normal CSS.

Is there a way to enable (add) all the special features of sass to the IntelliJ auto completion for functions like "lighten()" etc., too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several tickets related to this in the [JetBrains issue tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net), [this one for example](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RUBY-8817). Fortunately, it seems they [plan on fixing it soon](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/RUBYDEV/Development+Roadmap) though.

Comment: The ticked you linked is for RubyMine, but the same is true for IntelliJ IDEA 10.5.2. This feature is broken at the moment.